# Easiest way to return sum of a matrix's neighbors in numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix, scipy

I am trying to make a program that needs a matrix's neighbor(excluding itself) sum ex:

```
 matrix([[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 0]])
```

would return:

```
matrix([[1, 2, 1],
        [1, 3, 1],
        [2, 2, 2]])
```

I have a working code here but its big and messy and I'm new to numpy so I need some help cleaning it up and optimizing. (I feel like there has to be a better way)

example code:

```
import numpy as np

def NiSum(m):
    new = []
    for x in range(m.shape[0]-1):
        row = []
        for y in range(m.shape[1]-1):
            Ni = 0
            for a in [1,1],[1,0],[1,-1],[0,1],[0,-1],[-1,1],[-1,0],[-1,-1]:
                Ni += m[x+a[0],y+a[1]]
            row.append(Ni)
        new.append(row)
    return np.matrix(new)


example = np.matrix('0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; '*3+'0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0; '*3+'0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ')

NiSum(example)
```

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are summing all values in that `3x3` neighbourhood, but excluding the element itself. So, we can use [`Scipy's 2D convolution`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html) and subtract that input array/matrix from it for the desired output, like so -

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

convolve2d(a,np.ones((3,3),dtype=int),'same') - a
```

Sample run -

```
In [11]: a
Out[11]: 
matrix([[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 0]])

In [12]: convolve2d(a,np.ones((3,3),dtype=int),'same') - a
Out[12]: 
matrix([[1, 2, 1],
        [1, 3, 1],
        [2, 2, 2]])
```

Or simply form a kernel with all ones but zero at the center and use the same 2D convolution -

```
In [31]: kernel = np.array([[1,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]])

In [32]: np.asmatrix(convolve2d(a,kernel,'same'))
Out[32]: 
matrix([[1, 2, 1],
        [1, 3, 1],
        [2, 2, 2]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I'm having so many issues trying to install scipy.

Comment: `pip install scipy` doesn't work because I don't have scipy mkl
`pip install numpy-mkl` doesn't work because it can't find a matching version
`pip install http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/numpy-1.11.2+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl` doesn't work because 404 error 

I've never installed a packet before without just doing `pip install name` so im a little lost

Comment: @Whud You can post a new question on Scipy installation I believe. I am not too familiar with those installation steps.

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Define a function which computes the sum of all neighbors for a matrix entry, if they exist:

```
def sumNeighbors(M,x,y):
    l = []
    for i in range(max(0,x-1),x+2): # max(0,x-1), such that no negative values in range() 
        for j in range(max(0,y-1),y+2):
            try:
                t = M[i][j]
                l.append(t)
            except IndexError: # if entry doesn't exist
                pass
    return sum(l)-M[x][y] # exclude the entry itself
```

Then you can iterate for every entry in your matrix and pass its result into a new matrix N:

```
import numpy as np

M = [[1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]] 

M = np.asarray(M)
N = np.zeros(M.shape)

for i in range(M.shape[0]):
    for j in range(M.shape[1]):
        N[i][j] = sumNeighbors(M, i, j)

print "Original matrix:\n", M
print "Summed neighbors matrix:\n", N
```

**Output:**

```
Original matrix:
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]
Summed neighbors matrix:
[[ 11.  19.  13.]
 [ 23.  40.  27.]
 [ 17.  31.  19.]]
```